# type for all indices of class or subclass

Tags: typescript, indexing, types

I am using a typescript class containing data and its validation:

```
class Person extends ValueWithValidation {
    constructor(name: string, phone: string) {
        super()
        this.name = name
        this.phone = phone
    }

    name: string
    phone: string
}
```

The base class `ValueWithValidation` looks like this:

```
class ValueWithValidation {
    constructor() {
        this.isValid = true
        this.validationError = {}
    }

    isValid: boolean
    validationError: any;
}
```

The property `validationError` should contain an object with the same keys as the child class `Person`, i.e.

```
person.validationError = {
    name: 'some string',
    phone: 'some other string',
}
```

What is the correct type for `validationError`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the correct way to do it but it works:

```
class ValueWithValidation<T> {
  constructor() {
    this.isValid = true
    this.validationError = {}
  }

  isValid: boolean
  validationError: {[K in Exclude<keyof T, keyof ValueWithValidation<{}>>]?: T[K]}
}

class Person extends ValueWithValidation<Person> {
  constructor(name: string, phone: string) {
    super()
    this.name = name
    this.phone = phone
  }

  name: string
  phone: string
}
```

## Explanation

```
{
  [
    K in // type K in
    Exclude<keyof T, keyof ValueWithValidation<{}>> // gets keys of T (e.g. Person) that aren't the keys of ValueWithValidation (isValid, validationError)
  ]?: // optional key
    T[K] // typeof K in T (e.g. Person['name'] (string))
}
```

Comment: Thank you cherryblossom. The only drawback I see is that I need to type the class name of the subclass two times. Does anyone know a solution without this duplication?

Answer (score 0):

After implementing cherryblossom's answer, I realized that it is also possible to do the following:

```
class ValueWithValidation {
    constructor() {
        this.isValid = true
        this.validationError = {}
    }

    isValid: boolean
    validationError: {[K in Exclude<keyof this, keyof ValueWithValidation>]?: string};
}
```

This way I can omit the type variable `T`.